# Configure EtherumJ with Redis

Tags: ethereumj

How do you configure the host/login/password of Redis to use with Ethereumj.

in *ethereumj.conf*, I have the values:

```
# Key value data source values: [leveldb/redis/mapdb]
keyvalue.datasource = redis

# Redis cloud enabled flag.
# Allows using RedisConnection for creating cloud based data structures.
redis.enabled=true
```

It seems to be developped with Spring Boot Redis, but the addition of a application.properties file containing has no effects, and it still create a local redis database:

```
spring.redis.host=myhost
spring.redis.port=6379
```